# Open a spreadsheet created using ClosedXML in Microsoft Excel without a temp file being created

Tags: excel, file, temp, closedxml

For security reasons I cannot create a temp file as the contents of the spreadsheet are sensitive to the client.  However, they need to inspect the spreadsheet in Excel without creating this temp file.
How can I launch the spreadsheet in excel without creating a temporary xlsx file?
Any help or a pointer towards a solution would be great (I have searched for a similar question to no avail).

Comment: afaik, the temp file is created by the OS for recovery reasons - not something controlled by the end user so I'm not sure you can actually do this.

Comment: I have a solution which does not fit the bill of the question. I used SaveAs(path) then I created an interop application and made a worksheet from the path as a template with Add method.  Then I deleted the file located at the path. It remained open in Excel with users ability to then save it without having the xlsx file saved without clients permission.